# Drawing on ImageView - createBitmap crash

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to draw on ImageView and when i try to create Bitmap, program crashes.
First i created variable

```
private ImageView backgroudn;
```

in onCreate method i pointed background to object in my xml file.

```
this.backgroudn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivbackground);
drawGrid ();
```

But now when i want to draw on this ImageView in function drawGrid (), it first returns me size of ImageView as width = 0 and height = 0. Why what did i do wrong?

```
private void drawGrid () {

    int height = this.backgroudn.getHeight();
    int width = this.backgroudn.getWidth();

    // return's height = width = 0
    System.out.println("height: " + height + " width: " + width);

    // where program crashes.
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


    Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    int sizeW = width/7;
    int sizeH = height/7;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        c.drawLine(i*sizeW, 0, i*sizeW, height, p);
        c.drawLine(0, i*sizeH, width, i*sizeH, p);
    }

    backgroudn.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that error is just because height and width was 0. But still i need those values, what can i do?

Here is my xml code:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivbackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_row="0" />
```